# Just another puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, language

Another puzzle.... it goes:

> ory-llo baste-bet-iram-el ↻-yang-to-lp? 32 3543 X442

Hint 1:

> Each word separated by dashes is half a word. You need the missing half.

Hint 2:

> Note the symbol.

Hint 3:

> Note the digits as well.

Hint 4:

> The missing letters go on only one side.

Hint 5:

> One of the completed versions of the words has three words.

Hint 6:

> It is referring to a symbol.

Comment: Oui. Yes. I accept!

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to just give us a cipher, with nothing else; a hint perhaps would be useful because it will take long amounts of time to find the cipher

Comment: I cannot find an 8 letter word ending with iram.

Comment: Um.............. Ju jt nz gbwpsjuf npotufs jo b wjefp hbnf.

Comment: In *Hint 2*, are you referring to $\circlearrowright$ or **yang**? ...Or both?

Answer (score 1):

**New Guess**

I'm still pretty lost, but let's see how this works:

> Since we're given half of a word, maybe we have to do the above process with the half of the word that we're missing. The only word where "BASTE" is a half is "ALABASTERS", so "ALARS". "IRAM" is half of the word "TIRAMISU", so "TISU". "LP" is half of a bunch of words, but "HELP" is the most common, so "HE". The most common word containing "LLO" is "PHYLLO", so "PHY". The only English word where "YANG" is a half is "BOWYANGS", so "BOWS". We can then start to put words together: _ _ _ - PHY ALARS - _ _ _ - TISU - _ _  ↻-BOWS- _ _ - HE. The ↻ symbol might mean that we have to rearrange the last line, ie. HE - _ _ - BOWS. Then using the numbers again as before, we get _P A_I- _OS, so far.

**New New Guess, with @Simon**

> The numbers have to do with the lengths of the missing parts of the words. 
>  Then: 
>  PRIory-CEllo yields PRICE...... 
>  LAMbaste-**_-TiramISU-_____ doesn't seem to yield any correct 15 letter word.... 
>  BOWyangS-_**-HElp. Inverted yields HElp-___-BOWyangS, which doesn't seem to yield any correct 10 letter word either....

Comment: ......... NO! NO! I can make hint 1 more clear. And you interpreted the symbol (hint 2), but in the wrong way.

Comment: Is this any more correct than before, or am I farther away now?

Comment: I'm guessing rot13(gur ahzoref ercerfrag gur yratguf bs rnpu unys-jbeq? v.r. VENZ vf ba 4, fb GVENZVFH jbhyq jbex orpnhfr gur bgure unys, G___VFH vf bayl 4 yrggref )

Comment: That's actually a good point @Simon, I can try to look for words that fit that bill. Technically that means that these aren't "half"-words though ;P

Comment: La nachon. Anyone else submit answers.

Comment: Haha you don't want me to keep searching? :P My guesses must be too far off!

Comment: psst... lambaste is correct, and the numbers, but the circle arrow is not reverse... think of other meanings... and try to keep your guesses in different answers... I have a new hint.

Comment: @Ikura priory and cello and help are incorrect? and thanks for the hint. Does the circle mean rot13(ercrng) instead? I prefer keeping my guesses in the same answer so that multiple answers by the same person don't bog down the question.

Comment: Just go through every meaning of it. I don't wanna spoil

Answer (score 0):

Potential partial answer for second segment:

> **LAM**baste; **ALPHA**bet; **RESH**iram (that's not a word -_-); ???el - these are all letters from other alphabets: lam from the Arabic alphabet, alpha from the Greek alphabet, resh from the Hebrew alphabet... and there's way too many different possibilities for the last one. The Latin representations of each of these spell out **LAR?**, though. (I don't even want to think about how many different answers there are for ???el and ????to... >_<)

Comment: The first sentence, I give a yeshiram.... But, really, do other parts. qplfnpo

Answer (score 0):

This is super stretchy but it's my only guess.

> The theme is symbols/ alphabets?

The first part

> **MEM**ory, **CE**llo, **LAM**baste, **ALPHA**bet, **RESH**iram (Take half of the word as an answer)(CREDIT: Level 51)

The second part is different because

> ↻ indicates that you take the whole word as an answer instead of just the missing half like the first part.

So

> **YIN-YANG**, **LEGATO**, **HELP or YELP**? < This, I don't know at all.

NOTE:

> Reshiram is not a word but you have hinted that ROT25(Ju jt nz gbwpsjuf npotufs jo b wjefp hbnf.) and ROT25(qplfnpo).